How do I clean up the Jetbrains Remote Cache?
I see that my remote machine had a huge space taken up by this.
Are these caches or the required files for remote development with IntelliJ. How do I manage space for Remote Development with IntelliJ ?
> sudo du -h / | sort -rh | head -n 20

9.5G    /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains
7.7G    /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist
7.7G    /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev
4.0G    /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/3f9fdcd33c262_CLion-2024.2.3
3.8G    /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/c37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2

